# Problem in undertsanding the definition of Neighborhood (and it's followed corollaries) in Metric Space Topology

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, elementary-set-theory, metric-spaces

**Mtric Sets : (Topology)**

> > (1) Definition : Let $(M,d)$ be any metric set. Let $p$ be a fixed
> > point in M, and let ϵ be any positive real number. We define a
> > 'neighborhhod $N(p,ϵ)$ of $p$, with radius $ϵ$ as follows :
> > $N(p,ϵ) = \{q \in M : d(p,q) < ϵ\}$.
>
> > (2) Let $A$ be any set with metric defined by $d(p,q) = 0$ if $p=q$, and
> > $d(p,q)=1$ if $p \neq q$. Then $N(p,ϵ) = p$ if $ϵ \leq 1$ and $N(p,ϵ) = A$.
> >
> > (3) A 'deleted neighborhood $N^{′}(p,ϵ)$ is defined as follows :
> > $N^{′}(p,ϵ) = {q, 0,d(p,q)<ϵ}$. Note that, $N^{′}(p,ϵ)$ has precisely
> > one point less than $N(p,ϵ)$ that is, $N^{′}(p,ϵ) = N(p,ϵ) - {p}$.

I'm unable to undertsand these 3 points in terms of Metric Space topology, I want logical (with Cantors) explanation of these 3 points.

**Edit :**

(1) I did undertsnad the first definitons more or less, since it's the key point I want some detailed (geometrical wise) explanation of this definiton along with the rest 2 points.

Yes, I tried to think about it, but I'm not convinced enough by my way of thinking, I'm missing the core understanding of it.

(2) Yes, I thought in terms of $\mathbb{R}^2$. $N(p,ϵ)$ is the set of points insde a circel with center $p=(a,b)$  and radius $ϵ$, described as : $\{x,y : (x-a)^2+(y-b)^2 < ϵ^2\}$.

(3) So, the point (1) I undertsnad in the sense of given meaning but I can't undertsand when I use the same key definition to understand the points (2) and (3).

Comment: What don’t you understand?

Comment: have you tried to think about it yet? like, write down points with neighborhoods or something?

Comment: In the definition, try using set notation: $N(p,\epsilon) = \{q \in M : d(p,q) < \epsilon\}.$ What does this mean geometrically? Think of what happens in $\mathbb{R}^2.$

Comment: Formatting tip:  use `\{` to get `{` in MathJax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (1), maybe instead of thinking of an arbitrary metric space, just think of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the usual Euclidean metric, i.e. just the 'distance' that you're used to in everyday life. More intuitively, think about an infinitely large sheet of paper where you can measure distance with a ruler. First thing you do now is draw any point on this paper and call it $p$. For convenience, let's fix $\epsilon = 1$ but note that any positive radius would be possible. So with that analogy in mind, what is now $N(p,1)$? We have that

$$N(p,1) = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^2 | d(p,x) < 1\},$$

so all points $x$ on your sheet of paper that are less than the distance 1 away from your initial point $p$. If you actually draw this on a piece of paper it should be clear to you that with the distance we are used to this leads to a circle of radius 1 around $p$, just without the border at the outside (these points would be exactly at the distance 1 from $p$.)

The thing now is, we can actually use this definition for other metrics, or 'distance functions' than the one we are used to in everyday life. For instance we can try to see what happens if you apply this reasoning to the metric you have defined in (2). Be aware that this doesn't work like a normal 'infinite sheet of paper' anymore, so you might have to adapt your intuition a bit.